# Getting error in jackson library code

Tags: jackson, dropwizard

We are using dropwizard version 0.6.3. When we try to upgrade version 0.7.0,  we are getting this error on service start.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: class com.fasterxml.jackson.module.afterburner.deser.SuperSonicBeanDeserializer overrides final method deserialize.(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;

Tried searching, didn't get any solution. When i looked into SuperSonicBeanDeserializer class, it has one override method. But the class SuperSonicBeanDeserializer is final. I'm not sure how to resolve this problem. Any solution/suggestion, will help us lot.

Comment: Most probably you have two versions of the Jackson library in your class path. How do you build your application?

Comment: Thanks. As part of one dependency mudule, different jackson version also included..

Comment: Can you get rid of the different Jackson version? Otherwise that may cause all kinds of problems. I recommend you to stick to the latest Jackson version that comes with Dropwizard.

Comment: It is especially important that version of Afterburner module is compatible with core Jackson components (jackson-core, jackson-databind): patch versions may differ, but minor version MUST match. It sounds like this is the root cause in your case.

Answer (score 10):

A look at the maven dependency tree should help find where the problem is:

`mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose`

Look for "omitted for conflict" within the results.  You likely have a version of jackson-databind older than 2.3.0 that is overriding the version in Dropwizard 0.7.

Comment: This solved the problem for me, and was able to fix it in two different ways. One specify jackson-databind as a dependency and set the version to 2.3.x, or Two set an exclusions on the dependency that was bringing in the old version of jackson.

Comment: You can also use: 'mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=:jackson-databind::' in order to get a more precise information of the paths to  this dependency