# Dropwizard upgrade from 0.6.2 to 0.7.1 error

Tags: jackson, yaml, dropwizard

I've this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: class
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.module.afterburner.deser.SuperSonicBeanDeserializer
>   overrides final method
>   deserialize.(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;

I'm upgrading dropwizard from 0.6.2 to 0.7.1 version.

I'm able to compile without errors but when I run my app, I've the error above.
I've already read this post: [Getting error in jackson library code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23720251/getting-error-in-jackson-library-code) but without success.

How can I solve?

Comment: Are you using any other libraries that include the `com.fasterxml.jackson.core` library? Such as aws-sdk, etc.

Comment: What does your POM look like? What was the result of running `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose`?

Comment: I've found the error, there is a conflict with AWS Amazon library. I've excluded jackson-annotation into my maven repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in my comment, if you use any other libraries that include `com.fasterxml.jackson.core`, the versions may conflict. To resolve this, put an exclude statement around the conflicting library. Using the aws-sdk library I mentioned in my comment, the exclude would look roughly something like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.12</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```